# Initializing base class members using the scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, syntax

So here's two classes:

```
class Animal{
  private:
    char* m_sound; 

  public:
    Animal(char* s);
};

class Cat : public Animal{
  private:
    char* m_name;

  public: 
    Cat(char* n, char* s);
}
```

I want to define this classes outside of the class declaration:

```
Animal::Animal(char* s) : m_sound(s){
} 

Cat::Cat(char* n, char* s) : m_name(n), m_sound(s){
}
```

I know that this definition of Cat will not work and I have seen examples on how to define the members of a base class within the derived class definition, but how can I do this with the scope resolution operator? Is this possible?

Comment: In your example you want the Cat initializer to call one of the Animal constructors. You can access public or protected base class members in the constructor code itself, inside the braces {}. There's nothing in your example that needs scope resolution. Now, if both classes had a m_name member then you could use `Cat::m_name` and `Animal::m_name`.

Comment: You just pass the parameter on to the base class constructor - `Cat::Cat(char* n, char* s) : m_name(n), Animal(s)`

Comment: @BoPersson That should be `Animal(s), m_name(n)` since the base class will be constructed before members of the derived class.

Comment: @1201 - It doesn't matter in this case, but yes that is what happens.

Comment: @BoPersson some compilers issue a diagnostic (warning) if the order is wrong.

Comment: @1201 - If they do, you can change the order. In this specific case, the result is the same anyway.